# How can I exclude the link for the current page when I have a list of links in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 with Panels and Views.

I've configured a view to list several links to different panels.  This view is displayed as a content pane on each of the respective panels to allow for easy navigation.  However, this means that the link to each page is shown on that page as a link, which is unsightly and confusing.

Within Views, is there a way to configure the filters, etc. to hide or (best case) rewrite the link so that it is shown as plaintext rather than a link if it is pointing to the page being shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with displaying node revision links on a node page, views would display the link to the current node being displayed. To fix this I edited the views template file and checked myself whether the link pointed to the current page or not and only displayed a link if it wasn't to the current node.